# 'NoMethodError: private method called for Class' when testing public method that calls private method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, automated-tests

I'm trying to test a public function that calls a private function. This is a simplified version of the public function:

```
def gera_documento
  set_layout #the private method
  return documento.to_pdf
end
```

The spec specifically tests `gera_documento`, not `set_layout`:

```
it "retorna um PDF" do
  expect(Gerador.new(@doc).gera_documento.render[0,4]).to eq('%PDF')
end
```

The test fails with the following error:

```
Failure/Error: set_layout

     NoMethodError:
       private method `set_layout' called for #<Gerador:0x00564d2bd5e868>
```

The test passes if I make `set_layout` public. What is happening, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use instance eval for this like

```
@your_controller = SpqwerController.new
@your_controller.instance_eval{ set_layout }
```

Comment: I think I didn't get the syntax right. Here's what I did: `gerador = Gerador.new(@doc);
   gerador.instance_eval{set_layout};
   expect(gerador.gera_documento.render[0,4]).to eq('%PDF')` (I added the ;'s because line breaks don't show on comments)